# Undefined control sequence \text when importing Matlab figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, external-files, matlab

I'm following a [tutorial](http://www.howtotex.com/packages/beautiful-matlab-figures-in-latex/) to import Matlab figures through `tikz`, however after trying to compile the `.tex` file I get the following error:

```
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros (./mysphere.tikz
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \text 

l.1005 \end{axis}

?
```

I created the `mysphere.tikz` file exactly as described in the link, and I am including the file in LaTeX as indicated:

```
\begin{figure} 
    \centering 
    \newlength\figureheight
    \newlength\figurewidth
    \setlength\figureheight{6cm}
    \setlength\figurewidth{6cm}
    \input{mysphere.tikz}
    \caption{A plot of a sphere}
    \label{fig:sphere}
\end{figure}
```

I am using TeXworks and `pdflatex` to compile the file, on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Could you please provide a full compilable (but minimal) document (MWE), so that we can see which packages you are using. The error is about the undefined `\text`, which usually comes from the `amsmath` packages AFAIK, so check if that package is loaded. Also, we need the name and version of your (La)TeX distribution and packages, not of your OS. I assume you are using *TeX Live 2012* (or is it still 2010) with no package updates as it is provided by Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: We actually need to see the code inside the `mysphere.tikz` to understand the problem.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

So I found the error. Apparently the *matlab2tikz* script "overcomplicates" the title conversion from matlab, with `a sphere: x^2+y^2+z^2` from Matlab ending up as
`$\text{a sphere: x}^\text{2}\text{+y}^\text{2}\text{+z}^\text{2}$`, while `a sphere: $x^2+y^2+z^2$` is a more correct translation (no errors whatsoever with this title).

Comment: +1. Incidentally, that's also the final step in the tutorial you linked to...

Comment: does the matlab doc not say you need to load amsmath?