# Lualatex capacity exceeded with Gb's of free RAM

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, tikz-external, memory

I'm trying to compile dense graphs generated my matlab2tikz (file size ~ 50Mb). I'm running lualatex and externalising with lualatex

```
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
```

With file sizes of ~ 5Mb things work ok, but the jump to 50Mb fails. When I look at the profile of the 5Mb run, the processes use a few 100Mb of RAM, and the externalised pdf is about 1Mb. This leads me to think that the jump to 50Mb should be fine. Moreover, the lualatex runtime is about linear in the number of data points according to the pgfplots manual, so memory consumption must be as well.

The lualatex error at the moment is that `TeX capacity exceeded [token memory size=75830065]`. This is strange since I have at least 12Gb RAM available when I run the process, so I don't think memory, if dynamically allocated, should cause this. Moreover, when I look at the profile it fails while it's only consuming a few 100Mb of RAM, so there's still a lot of room to grow.

1) Is there some other errant call to pdflatex, or something similar that isn't part of the dynamic memory allocation?

2) If not, why is lualatex failing? Is there some other parameter that I can expand?

Running TeX Live 2014 on Windows 8 with TeXstudio. Here's the end of the log file:

```
("../../Matlab/simulations/sigma f-poly k-3 i-0.0001 s-0.001 nt-1 nb-0.0
1 const-1 HDD-0 minT-40 ds-100"
Runaway text?
 \par \begin {axis}[width=\threeW , height=\threeH , scale only axis,\ETC.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [token memory size=75830065].
<argument> ...52 0.0961556466390988\\ 0.3653 0.096155646\8ETC

l.2002060 \end{axis}

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 27544 strings out of 494693
 100000,75830065 words of node,token memory allocated 15902 words of node memory still in use:
   146 hlist, 17 vlist, 15 rule, 116 disc, 34 math, 400 glue, 167 kern, 47 penal
ty, 1534 glyph, 162 glue_spec, 4 action, 3 temp, 1 if_stack, 8 local_par, 3 dir,
 4 pdf_start_link, 4 pdf_end_link, 3 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 2:32,3:415,4:706,5:138,6:1117,7:73,8:36,9:345,10:106
 30092 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 53 fonts using 1491859 bytes
 62i,20n,83p,1229b,546s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

**EDIT**

As discussed in the comments, I tried preprocessing one of these files. Here's a MWE not of the memory error (because the file is now ~ 5Mb) but of the new error. Removing the externalisation fails here as well.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=compiled/]

\begin{document}

\newlength{\threeW}
\newlength{\threeH}
\setlength{\threeW}{1.2in}
\setlength{\threeH}{1.8in}

\input{small.tex}

\end{document}
```

[small.tex](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/7BQcbL32/0/blob?download)

**EDIT 2**

It looks like with large files lualatex failed when it saw `$\text{z}$` in an axis label (that should of course be `$z$`, it was in the form as a result of the matlab2tikz process), and that's what caused the error, similar to [Undefined control sequence \text when importing Matlab figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119997/undefined-control-sequence-text-when-importing-matlab-figures). That's strange because in small files this error isn't thrown. This is so absurd. I'll report back if this isn't actually the solution.

Comment: Is it necessary to create those graphs with that big data? I mean, couldn't you reduce the points with barely no change in the “print”?

Comment: @Manuel, no it certainly isn't necessary. But even when I downsample with `each nth point=1000` it doesn't help and I get the same memory error, which leads me to think it's not managing to even process the file, which is strange because 50Mb surely doesn't need more than 12 Gb to be processed.

Comment: @bjorne Make a downsample via `matlab` and not via `pgfplots`: 2,000,000 points is to big!

Comment: @PaulGaborit, I did that as well. If I preprocess the files and comment out or delete say 99% of the data lines it still fails (but not a memory issue) saying Extra `}` and then Missing `}`, which seems contradictory. When I look at the processed file, it's fine, all the brackets are in tact, I only delete data lines, so this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Manuel, I'm not sure what there is to tell. The memory issue is frustrating me because it's not my code that causes it. With the preprocessed files I'm less certain that it's not my fault, maybe my preprocessing code messes things up, so those errors might be my fault, which is why I didn't really discuss them in my question. I'll work on a MWE.

Comment: This happened to me today as well with a large tikz file exported from matlab.  I have over 16GB of RAM available, and I can watch the ram usage and lualatex is definitely not allocating too much RAM here. Also, @bjorne, I don't have the $\text{z}$ problem in my tikz file...the token memory size reported is 63191721

Comment: @daaxix, you may not have the exact same error, but it's worth checking for similar symptoms, i.e. tex syntax/compliance errors within the tikz file. From what I remember my conclusions were that this wasn't really an underlying memory issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer, since it does not solve the problem, nor add much clarification, but I think it is worth writing it and it is too long for a comment.

Something is wrong about your profile showing only 100Mb of used memory. Only the token memory used is much larger, as I'll show in short, and there is also other kind of memory in  use (string memory, node memory, etc.)

I searched for the string `"token memory size"`, which appears in your output, in luatex source code. It appears at [`textoken.w`](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/systems/luatex/base/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/textoken.w):

```
        smemory_word *new_fixmem;       /* the big dynamic storage area */
        t = (fix_mem_max / 5);
        new_fixmem =
            fixmemcast(realloc
                       (fixmem, sizeof(smemory_word) * (fix_mem_max + t + 1)));
        if (new_fixmem == NULL) {
            runaway();          /* if memory is exhausted, display possible runaway text */
            overflow("token memory size", fix_mem_max);
        } else {
            fixmem = new_fixmem;
        }
```

So we can do some computations from here. The number which is output next to the message "token memory size" is the current value of variable `fix_mem_max`, which happens to be `75830065` in your case. This is the number of `smemory_word`s reserved for the token memory. Each `smemory_word` is a structure (defined in `textoken.h`) with two fields, each one of the type `halfword`, which is defined elsewhere as an integer of 32 bits. So each "token" is 64bits, and thus the actual memory allocated for the token list is `fix_mem_max`*8 in bytes.

In your case this means `75830065*8`=`606640520` bytes, which is roughly 578Mb. Still far from your 12Gb, but much more than the 100Mb your profiler reported.

The error is triggered when TeX exhausts the available token memory (the 578Mb allocated in your case), and tries to expand it via `realloc`, and fails because the main system memory is exhausted too.

You can see in the above code that the new tried size is `sizeof(smemory_word) * (fix_mem_max + t + 1))` where `t` has been computed previously as `fix_mem_max/5`, so in your case the numbers are: `8*(75830065+75830065/5+1)` which gives `727968632` bytes (around 694Mb).

Although these amounts are far from the 12Gb of RAM you have, they are only the token memory. As said before, there are other kind of memories used by LuaTex, so the total can be well around 1Gb or more. Still, I don't know if this is enough to explain the problem or if there is some bug inside LuaTeX which prevents the actual use of all the available RAM. Nevertheless, these are big numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. I've worked around the problem as mentioned, so it's less mission critical for me to investigate the source of this frustration. But this is an interesting start. Something is definitely fishy. I've upvoted.

Comment: If lualatex is built as a 32 bit process, it will only be able to access 2GB, 3GB, or 4GB of memory depending on how it was compiled (for windows at least, which is where my issue reared its head), this is consistent with the OP's issues.